# left text alignment works different with different letters

Tags: html, css

Please see the cases below :

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

I'm trying to align above h1 (i.e Add Maintenance) with below field label. But the left alignment looks different with different letters.

In example 1 A in `Add Maintenance` "touches" the left border.

In example 2 C doesn't touch the left border and has some space.

In example 3 B doesn't touch the left border and has some space but space is slightly bigger than in example 2.

How do I align them in a straight line?

Side note :

This is all same site, I just changed the value of h1 text

Comment: maybe [this](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/letter-spacing.html)  link will be helpful ?

Comment: I doubt you can, this seems to be characteristics of your font.

Comment: why did I get down-vote, did I not ask the question appropriately ?

Comment: some people see the question too easy or to obvious and just down vote it with no feedback and walk away ... unfortunately you can't avoid them. I will up vote it to counterbalance (is not a bad question) but I agree with @emartel ... it depends on the font (should I say typeface?) you are using.

Comment: Random downvoting without giving a reason seems to be relatively common around here. Some days it's frustrating to help and get a downvote for an answer that works without reason. They shouldn't let you downvote without a comment in my opinion. As to your question emartel is right, it's the built in kerning of the font itself. You could probably play with the left margin a bit to fix it but is that's up to you.

Comment: I'm going to accept the only answer because this is obviously font problem, customer demands it fixed. but it cannot be with same css using same margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try different font because in Arial "B" and "C" letter has some space before it, but "A" does not.
You Can notice it in this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b369T.png